# How to detect if there is intersection using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I am using matplotlib to plot these two line graphs. However, only sometimes my graphs would have an intersection. How can I detect if my line graphs have an intersection?

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")

x1 = df['A'].tolist()
x1 = np.array(x1)

y1 = df['D'].tolist()
y1 = np.array(y1)

x2 = df2['X'].tolist()
x2 = np.array(x2)

y2 = df2['Y'].tolist()
y2 = np.array(y2)

plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the index of intersection points with:

```
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2))).flatten()
```

If there is one or more intersections, `idx` is a list of intersection points indeces, otherwise it is an empty list.

- **one or more intersections**

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
  x2 = np.linspace(-2, 5, 1000)
  y1 = np.sin(x1)
  y2 = np.cos(x2) + 1

  idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2))).flatten()

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()

  ax.plot(x1, y1, 'blue')
  ax.plot(x2, y2, 'red')

  plt.show()
  ```

  ```
  print(len(idx))
  2
  ```

  [image]
- **no intersections**

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
  x2 = np.linspace(-2, 5, 1000)
  y1 = np.sin(x1)
  y2 = np.cos(x2) + 2

  idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y1 - y2))).flatten()

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()

  ax.plot(x1, y1, 'blue')
  ax.plot(x2, y2, 'red')

  plt.show()
  ```

  ```
  print(len(idx))
  0
  ```

  [image]

Comment: I'm getting this error :  operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (674,) (14,) . I think its due to the different numpy sizes. It took 674 points to plot the first graph and only 14 points for the second one. Do you know any ways to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

This code prints 'intersect' if the y-values cross each other at some  point.

```
mark = y1[0]-y2[0]

for i in range(len(y1)):
    if mark > 0:
        if y1[i]-y2[i] < 0:
        print('intersect')
    elif mark < 0:
        if y1[i]-y2[i] > 0:
            print('intersect')
```